# my log4j SiftAppender doesn't generate files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I followed this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/serivcemix-configuring-sift)

I have this code, but no log file was written.

What am i missing?

here is my [code](https://github.com/elad2109/log4j_sift/blob/master/src/main/java/com/waze/rr_logger/SiftExampleLog4j.java): https://github.com/elad2109/log4j_sift/blob/master/src/main/java/com/waze/rr_logger/SiftExampleLog4j.java

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class SiftExampleLog4j {

    static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SiftExampleLog4j.class);

    public void log() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id","MyGooApp");

        logger.error("example1");

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id","MyFooApp");

        logger.error("example2");
    }
}
```

log4j.properties

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, sift, osgi:VmLogAppender

# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=session_id
log4j.appender.sift.default=no_session_id
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=$\\{session_id\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

Comment: Change your appender file to log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=$\\{userid\\}.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [step by step tutorial](http://blog.nanthrax.net/2014/08/mdc-logging-with-apache-karaf-and-camel/) is given here. Please follow the link.

Github Project Link: https://github.com/jbonofre/blog-mdc

---

### UPDATE:

You have missed to set up a simple configuration that logs on the console. You have to add `BasicConfigurator.configure();` in `SiftExampleLog4j.java` class.

**SiftExampleLog4j.java**

```
package com.waze.rr_logger;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class SiftExampleLog4j {

    static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(SiftExampleLog4j.class);

    public void log() {
        // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
        BasicConfigurator.configure(); // You have missed to add this

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id", "MyGooApp");

        logger.error("example1");

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id", "MyFooApp");

        logger.error("example2");
    }
}
```

### Console Output:

> 0 [main] ERROR com.waze.rr_logger.SiftExampleLog4j  - example1
>
> 0 [main] ERROR com.waze.rr_logger.SiftExampleLog4j  - example2

For more, you can follow the [tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: where is the log eventually? the root of the project or the `home folder` of my mac?

Comment: @user1065869 for your home folder you can check https://github.com/jbonofre/blog-mdc/blob/master/osgi/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg

Comment: still doesn't generate the log files. can you please have a look? here is my code https://github.com/elad2109/log4j_sift

Comment: @user1065869 I have updated answer. Please have a look. If any kind of issue occurs, please inform.

Comment: I have added the missing line, and yet i see no log files generated. Can you please have a look at my l4j.properties?

Comment: @EladBenda2 OK. Now you want to log in a file `myLogFile.log`. This is your requirement. Am I right ??

Comment: No, according to my code there should be two output log files: `MyGooApp .log` and `MyFooApp.log`. However I

Comment: where should they be?